# Hide/Show DIV from a href

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div which contains a google map, when the page loads I want to have the div hidden until I click the link to view. My problem is that the div always shows when the page loads. I can't for the life of me figure out why it wont show as hidden until clicked.

```
<a href="#" class="btn blue btn-block" onclick="toggle('showmap')">View on Map <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i></a>
```

This is my div which holds the map (haven't included as no need to)

```
<div id="showmap">
</div>
```

javascript

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    function toggle(id) {
        var state = document.getElementById(id).style.display;
            if (state == 'block') {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
            } else {
                document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
        }
    }
</script>
```

I've swapped the block & none around and still no joy,

How is it possible?

I did have it working through using a submit button, but I have more code that uses submit button to update a form to my db and everytime I clicked on the Show/Hide div it uploaded data, so I'm trying it this way unless you can have multiple submit on a page?

Comment: Use CSS to hide it initially. If you wait for JS to process it may 'flash' before hiding.

Comment: You have tagged this question as 'jQuery', yet your code is native JS. Are you looking for a jQ implementation or did you mis-tag?

Answer (score 2):

You can hide the element with CSS on initial page load:

```
#showmap {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for all the replies, I've managed to hide the div when the page loads now, but when I click the button to show the div, it flashes through as I see the little favicon move but the div doesn't open. I've tried each option through the replies

Answer (score 0):

The div will have the style display set to block by default so it will always be shown when the page is loaded as it is now. Preferable set the display property to none

```
<div id="showmap" style="display:none;"></div>
```

Or you can set it in javascript on when the page has been loaded

```
window.onload(function () {
    document.getElementById("showmap").style.display = "none";
}
```

But doing it by css is the way to go here.

Answer (score 0):

Better to use jquery but your code is not working because you need to do in this style

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        toggle('map');
    })
    function toggle(id) {
        var state = document.getElementById(id).style.display;
        if (state == 'block') {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'none';
        } else {
            document.getElementById(id).style.display = 'block';
    }
    return false;
}

</script>
<style>
#map{display:none}
</style>
```

or

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#map').toggle();
})
</script>
```

But the best way is to use css for hide(initial)
And ATTENTION FOR return false in your way of using